# SQL Server trigger only if a field is false prior to update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have written the trigger below that inserts values if the `emailstudio` column is updated. This column can be 0 or 1.

How can I write the trigger so that it only fires if the `emailstudio` column is changed from 0 to 1, not if it was already 1?

Thank you

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[RM_Est_Email_Trigger]
ON  [dbo].[K3_BriefHeader] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @estimate int, @Email_Date datetime, @status int, @emailstudio bit
    SET @estimate = (SELECT Estimate from inserted)
    set @Email_Date = GETDATE()
    SET @status = (SELECT Status from inserted)
    SET @emailstudio = (SELECT EmailStudio from inserted)

    IF UPDATE (EmailStudio)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[K3_EstimateEmailDate] ([Estimate], [Email_Date],[Status], [EmailStudio])
        VALUES (@estimate, @Email_Date, @status, @emailstudio)
    END
END
```

Comment: Your trigger is just broken because you are assuming that `inserted` has only one row.  I would suggest that you delete this question and review the SQL Server documentation on writing questions.  If you still have a problem, ask a new question with a trigger that might at least function.

Comment: Thanks for polite reply! The trigger DOES work. I records values ALL values from the K3_Briefheader table after changes. Thanks for your help Gordon

Comment: . . It does not work if you insert multiple rows at the same time.  The assumption that `inserted` has one row is a fatal error in the trigger.

Comment: It only inserts 1 row at a time.

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert INTO [dbo].[K3_EstimateEmailDate] (
    [Estimate]
   ,[Email_Date]
   ,[Status]
   ,[EmailStudio]
)
SELECT Estimate
      ,GETDATE()
      ,status
      ,1
FROM inserted
     LEFT JOIN deleted
         ON deleted.<primarykey> = inserted.<primarykey>
WHERE inserted.emailstudio = 1
      AND (deleted.emailstudio is null -- inserted
           OR deleted.emailstudio = 0) -- updated
```

Comment: Thank you AdrianM. Ill give this a try.